# comparing two date arrays and to find index in python

Tags: python, arrays, date, datetime, numpy

I've a data matrix (in numpy) format where 0th column contains dates in YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS format. I need to remove dates which repeat more than once in an hour.

I've converted the date column into a date time object and then with np.unique I removed duplicate entries. But I'm unable to find the index of unique array to extract data from the main matrix.

What I've done that

data is an 11X6 matrix,in which 2 elements are repeating. I need those 2 element to be removed.

2015-03-28 15:41:00,19.17,19.04,90,0.25,31.44
2015-03-28 15:43:00,19.17,18.99,90,0.76,31.44
2015-03-28 16:10:00,19.48,19.41,92,0.25,15.68
2015-03-28 16:13:00,19.59,19.41,92,0.51,15.68
2015-03-28 17:00:00,21.22,19.41,87,0.51,37.63
2015-03-28 18:00:00,21.66,21.18,79,0.0,23.82
2015-03-28 19:00:00,22.04,21.62,77,0.0,21.41
2015-03-28 20:00:00,22.05,21.68,77,0.0,13.71
2015-03-28 21:00:00,21.83,20.8,81,0.0,4.42
2015-03-28 22:00:00,21.06,20.64,81,0.0,4.81
2015-03-28 23:00:00,20.78,20.09,82,0.0,14.35

```
dates=list(np.unique(([dt.datetime.strptime(dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H'),'%Y-%m-%d %H') for x in data[:,0]])))

dates1=(([dt.datetime.strptime(dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H'),'%Y-%m-%d %H') for x in data[:,0]]))
```

then

```
uniq_data=data[np.squeeze(np.array(np.where(np.in1d(dates,dates1))).T),:]
```

but it gave the first 9 element but it still contains the repeating element.

can anyone tell that, Where I've gone wrong? or suggest a better method which fits in python numpy.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could use datetime.timedelta and remove any elements less than an hour apart? If you post the first column of the data array then it would be easier to help.

Comment: can any one say, how to use np.in1d, if all elements of first array are present in second array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the indexes of the elements that allow you to get the unique array: `numpy.unique(…, return_index=True)` is your friend.

Comment: Looking in the documentation does too. :) I encourage you to always check whether what you want is there: hopefully you are not the first one to need the feature that you are looking for. :)